ProtonVPN stopped working in 24.04
I used to use ProtonVPN with the GUI from Flathub. After a recent update, it stopped working. Every time I try to connect, it just immediately defaults to Error setting up tunnel. I thought that meant the GUI wasn't finding any back-end on my computer, so I tried reinstalling everything, but to my surprise when following the official guide I encountered a problem.
Basically when installing the ProtonVPN repository, the terminal tells me everything's fine, but then after trying to sudo apt get protonvpn it can't find the file! And sudo apt update shows me the repository isn't in the repository list!
Is this a compatibility problem with 24.04 that's going to get resolved, or did I mess up somewhere?

jf you install it from flathub you need to inform ProtonVPN owners and ask them to update their flatpak. Knowing the way VPN works it probably checks the OS, kernel and some other stuff and will refuse to work if those do not match the intended OS.

I tried installing from .deb and it doesn't work either

In my case the Error setting up tunnel occurred because somehow network-manager-openvpn package was uninstalled while upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1. I installed it manually:
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn

then restarted ProtonVPN and it was able to connect again!
There are likely other possible causes of this error.
This also happens to be the missing dependency needed for the flatpak version to work in non-GNOME flavors / DEs like Kubuntu / KDE.

I had the same problem. To fix it, I took these steps:

Uninstall stable release of protonvpn
Install the beta release:

wget https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian/dists/unstable/main/binary-all/protonvpn-beta-release_1.0.4_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./protonvpn-beta-release_1.0.4_all.deb
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install proton-vpn-gnome-desktop
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

