Unmet dependencies proton vpn
To whom it may concern,
I am trying to install Proton VPN and I get the following unmet dependencies. How could I fix it?
tomas@AK-47:~$ sudo apt install proton-vpn-gnome-desktop
[sudo] password for tomas: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec58 : Depends: libcodec2-1.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
                Depends: libdav1d5 (>= 0.2.1) but it is not installable
                Depends: libvpx7 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not installable
                Depends: libx264-163 (>= 2:0.163.3060+git5db6aa6) but it is not installable
 libavformat58 : Depends: libsrt1.4-gnutls (>= 1.4.4) but it is not installable
 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 : Depends: liblqr-1-0 (>= 0.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not installable
                         Recommends: gsfonts but it is not going to be installed
 libopenexr25 : Depends: libilmbase25 (>= 2.5.7) but it is not installable
 libvkd3d1:i386 : Depends: libvulkan1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 proton-vpn-gnome-desktop : Depends: proton-vpn-gtk-app but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: python3-proton-vpn-network-manager (>= 0.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: python3-proton-keyring-linux (>= 0.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
 wine-stable-amd64 : Depends: libasound2-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libcapi20-3
                     Recommends: libodbc2 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libodbc1 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libosmesa6 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libtiff5 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


The proton package that you downloaded is designed for Ubuntu 22.04 only. It is unlikely to work with any other release of Ubuntu. If you are running 22.04, be sure to have the universe repository enabled.

Thank you very much. I have the latest Ubuntu.

I have a working Proton VPN on 24.04. As far as I can remember It installed without issue using the Proton VPN install instructions. https://protonvpn.com/support/official-linux-vpn-ubuntu Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1511632/protonvpn-stopped-working-in-24-04 for some problems others have had with it. (What is WINE doing in the process?) Did you try 'sudo apt --fix-broken install'
